# How to return two values from function

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography, return-value

I have a function that generates cipher text for ElGamal encryption and I want to make return two values, but it returns only one. This is the code:

```
elgamalencrypt[m_, p_, g_, h_] := Module[{k, r, t},
SeedRandom[];
k = RandomInteger[{2,p-2}]; 
r = PowerMod[g,k,p] ; 
t = Mod[Power[h,k]*m,p] ;
Return [{r,t},Module];
]
```

I tried modifying the Return statement to:
`Return [{r,t}]` and
`Return [r,t]`, but I was keep getting an error about not enclosing the function, also tried this [Break::nofunc Continue::nofunc Return::nofunc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html)
 from documentation with no luck. If someone wants to try it out this is a test scenario:

`plaintext = toblocks["whataboutsecondbreakfast",3]`      this divides the plain text into blocks
`{230801,200102,152120,190503,151404,21805,11106,11920}`   output

`{p, g, h} = getelgamalpublickey[33]`        generate the values for the public key

`{22822153,8469268,20935791}`    output

`ciphertext =Map[elgamalencrypt[#,p,g,h]&,plaintext]`  and finally the encryption of each block
`{18627519,22660971,10034668,14492011,14579397,12595172,4596731,20282426}`    output

In the last output I want to have both r and t as result, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It is always helpful & recommended to include the definition of any necessary sub function you want to get help with, such as your `toblocks`; though, here, it does not seem to be entirely necessary.

Comment: For me your code works alright when using the values for `plaintext` and `p,g,h` as you describe (but gives different results). Can you try this with a fresh kernel? Nevertheless, as mikado shows the final `Return` is not needed in Mathematica, and it is best practice to avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost have this correct (I think).  You don't need to use `Return` (check the documentation, it doesn't do what you think).

The result of a module is simply the last value (more accurately, everything to the left of each `;` is discarded).

So having defined

```
elgamalencrypt[m_, p_, g_, h_] := 
 Module[{k, r, t}, SeedRandom[];
  k = RandomInteger[{2, p - 2}];
  r = PowerMod[g, k, p];
  t = Mod[Power[h, k]*m, p];
  {r, t}]


plaintext = {230801, 200102, 152120, 190503, 151404, 21805, 
  11106, 11920}
(* {230801, 200102, 152120, 190503, 151404, 21805, 11106, 11920} *)

{p, g, h} = {22822153, 8469268, 20935791}
(* {22822153, 8469268, 20935791} *)
```

you can make the call you want

```
ciphertext = Map[elgamalencrypt[#, p, g, h] &, plaintext]
(* {{6332963, 18176522}, {11878596, 18057113}, {832919, 
  18591539}, {9726226, 11069498}, {630979, 22520507}, {11489832, 
  2457708}, {6108168, 5897594}, {14498023, 4642761}} *)
```